# Finding Distinct results in SQL columns

Tags: sql

Below is the necessary info.

Table: `Parts`:

```
pid, Color
```

Table: `Supplier`

```
sid, sname
```

Table: `Catalog`

```
pid, sid
```

**I am trying to find the pid in parts that have multiple distinct suppliers. I really don't know what command to use to do this.
I know I will have to use INNER JOIN to connect Parts and Supplier but what command ensures that I only get pid that have multiple distinct suppliers?**

*What about finding parts that have NO suppliers? I know DISTINCT or COUNT could somehow be used but not sure how this would work.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
select * from parts
where pid in
(select pid
 from catalog
 group by pid
 having count(distinct sid) > 1)
```

Since you already have a table mapping a `pid` to one or more `sid`, you just retrieve the records in that table which have multiple `sid` values, and use the `HAVING` clause to implement this filter.

For the `pid` values with no `sid` values mapped to them, do a `left join` like so:

```
select * from
parts p
left join catalog c on p.pid = c.pid
where c.sid is null
```

The `is null` check ensures that only those `pid` values which do not have a mapped `sid` in the `Catalog` table are retrieved.

Answer (score 1):

**Find Parts with more than 1 supplier :**

```
SELECT
    p.Color
    ,COUNT(DISTINCT s.sname) as nbrSupName
FROM
    Parts p
    INNER JOIN Catalog c
        ON c.pid = p.pid
    INNER JOIN Supplier s 
        ON s.sid = c.sid
GROUP BY
    p.Color
HAVING
    COUNT(DISTINCT s.sname) > 1
```

Or :

```
SELECT
    p.Color
    ,s.sname
FROM
    (SELECT
        p.pid
        ,COUNT(DISTINCT s.sname) as nbrSupName
    FROM
        Parts p
        INNER JOIN Catalog c
            ON c.pid = p.pid
        INNER JOIN Supplier s 
            ON s.sid = c.sid
    GROUP BY
        p.Color) subquery
    INNER JOIN Catalog c
            ON c.pid = subquery.pid
    INNER JOIN Supplier s 
        ON s.sid = c.sid
GROUP BY
    p.Color
    ,s.sname
WHERE
    subquery.nbrSupName > 1
```

---

**Find Parts with NO supplier :**

```
SELECT
    p.Color
FROM
    Parts p
    LEFT JOIN Catalog c
        ON c.pid = p.pid
WHERE 
    c.sid IS NULL
GROUP BY
    p.Color
```

You can also use the 1st query with `COUNT(DISTINCT s.sname) = 0`

Comment: I get an error at the line: nbrSupName, the below poster's statement seems to work though....I feel really overwhelmed with all these commands and statements..

Answer (score 0):

If you only need the pid you can just work with the Catalog table

```
SELECT pid
FROM   Catalog
GROUP BY pid
HAVING COUNT(sid) > 1
```

that will work only if a Supplier is identified by the sid and not by the name.

To get the part with no supplier depent on how that information is stored.
If you have the pid in catalog with a `NULL` sid

```
SELECT pid
FROM   Catalog
WHERE  sid IS NULL
```

If there is no row in the catalog when the part has no supplier

```
SELECT p.pid
FROM   Parts p
       LEFT JOIN Catalog c on p.pid = c.pid
WHERE  c.pid IS NULL
```

If your database has the possibility to use a `MINUS` type command it's possible to do

```
SELECT pid
FROM   Parts
MINUS --EXCEPT in SQLServer 2005+
SELECT pid
FROM   Catalog
```